# Render UserControl in Same line as other controls in a <td>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to render Usercontrol in the same line as my other controls in . By default, it renders in new line for user control. 
Here is my Markup

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" EnableTheming="False" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Green"
                        Font-Bold="True" Style="margin-left: 18px"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="gotoHyperLink" Visible="false" EnableTheming="False" Font-Size="Small"
                        ForeColor="Green" Font-Bold="True" Style="margin-left: 2px" runat="server" NavigateUrl=""
                        Target="_blank">- To Wiki</asp:HyperLink>
                         <uc1:GoToRequestControl ID="GoToRequestControl1" runat="server" />
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>


        </tr>
```

I want to render the UC1 in the same line as previous two controls in Div if possible after some spacing to the right. Any fix on how to achieve this?

My User Control is designed using  despite that I want it to be on same line. Here is my Usercontrol's HTML

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnGo" BackColor="Transparent">
        <table style="margin-left:18px">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td>
                    <b><asp:Literal ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Coeus Request ID: " EnableTheming="False"></asp:Literal></b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbRequestId" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" Width="260px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btnGo_Click" OnClientClick="CheckLock();"
                        CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="" EnableTheming="False" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </td>       
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Why does it matter? New lines are meaningless in html.

Comment: Doesn't make much diff to me..My user wants them on same line...More of a UI reason...

Comment: The user cares about the output of view source???

Comment: Naahhh...I don't think so..

Comment: Then I'm confused. The new line has no effect on how it renders. If you're saying it renders on a new line then we'd need to see the html of the user control.

Comment: Obviously I am using a <Table> tag to design my usercontrol. I am positing in there my usercontrol's Html..

Comment: You're not showing the html of the user control. That is what we need to see to help you. The table is irrelevant.

Comment: Just add another <td> and place your user control in the new one.. So each <tr> has two <td>'s.